# Create Foreign Key SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-keys

How do I create a foreign key

from table tGeoAnswers column 'locationId'

to table tLocations column 'id'?

```
ALTER TABLE 
        tGeoAnswers 
ADD 
        FK_Answer_Location 
FOREIGN KEY 
        (locationId)
REFERENCES 
        tLocations(id)
```

I am trying this code that I found but I get the following error:

The definition for column 'FK_Answer_Location' must include a data type

Comment: You should specify what brand of RDBMS you're using.  E.g. Microsoft SQL Server 2005, MySQL 5.0, etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE tGeoAnswers ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Answer_Location ...
```

Otherwise it assumes you're adding a column called `FK_Answer_Location`.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming MsSql Server/T-SQL, use [ALTER TABLE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx):

```
 ALTER TABLE tGeoAnswers
 ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Answer_Location
 FOREIGN KEY (LocationId) REFERENCES tLocation (Id)
```

Answer (score -1):

Please have a look at the bottom of http://www.1keydata.com/sql/sql-foreign-key.html about the `ALTER TABLE ADD ... FOREIGN KEY` syntax.