# Syntax for naming foreign keys

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Using:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Table1Name
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (colname)
    REFERENCES dbo.Table2Name (colname)
```

I get a foreign key with a name like:
FK___colname__673F4B05

I want it to be named:
FK_Tabl1Name_Table2Name,

...so that it will be easy to read when browsing the DB structure in SSMS. I know I can go back into the GUI and do this, but I want to be able to script it.

So What's the SQL sytnax for adding a name to the FK? Nothing I've found online seems to bother with this.

Comment: Check the `ALTER TABLE` documentation at msdn: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx, section **O. Adding and dropping a FOREIGN KEY constraint**.

Comment: Also at `CREATE TABLE` documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979.aspx

Comment: @ypercube: Yes, the complete information is actually somewhat dispersed. One can find it quickly enough if one knows what to look for. Otherwise it takes time.

Comment: @Andriy: Yes, sometimes searching is easy only when one knows what to look for. But putting `add foreign key sql-server` to SO search box, yields this as first question/answer :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/842151/create-foreign-key-sql

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's how you can assign your chosen name to the foreign key constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Table1Name
  ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Tabl1Name_Table2Name
    FOREIGN KEY (colname) REFERENCES dbo.Table2Name (colname)
```